# Can't understand the char ** explained in csvgetline.c function from K&P book Practice of Programming

Tags: c

I have been trying to understand the revised csvgetline function in C from the chapter Interfaces of the book ["The Practice of Programming"](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop). I have highlighted the code that doesn't make sense to me.

```
#include "csv.h"

enum { NOMEM = -2 };          /* out of memory signal */
static char* line    = NULL;  /* input chars */
static char* sline   = NULL;  /* line copy used by split */
static int  maxline  = 0;     /* size of line[] and sline[] */
static char** field  = NULL;  /* field pointers */          // This is the problem!
static int  maxfield = 0;     /* size of field[] */
static int  nfield   = 0;     /* number of fields in field[] */

static char fieldsep[] = ","; /* field separator chars */
static char* advquoted(char *);
static int split(void);

/* endofline: check for and consume \r, \n, \r\n, or EOF */
static int endofline(FILE *fin, int c)
{ … }

/* reset: set variables back to starting values */
static void reset(void)
{ … }

/* csvgetline:  get one line, grow as needed */
/* sample input: "LU",86.25,"11/4/1998","2:19PM",+4.0625 */
char* csvgetline( FILE *fin )
{
   int i, c; 
   char *newl, *news;

   if (line == NULL) {     /* allocate on first call */
     maxline = maxfield = 1;
     line = (char *) malloc(maxline);
     sline = (char *) malloc(maxline);
     field = (char **) malloc(maxfield*sizeof(field));   // This is the problem!

     if (line == NULL || sline == NULL || field == NULL) {
       reset();

      return NULL;    /* out of memory */
    }
  }

  for (i=0; (c=getc(fin))!=EOF && !endofline(fin,c); i++) {
    if (i >= maxline-1) { /* grow line */
      maxline *= 2;   /* double current size */
      newl = (char *) realloc(line, maxline);
      if (newl == NULL) {
        reset();
        return NULL;
      }

      line = newl;
      news = (char *) realloc(sline, maxline);
      if (news == NULL) {
        reset();
        return NULL;
      }

      sline = news;
    }

    line[i] = c;
  }

  line[i] = '\0';

  if (split() == NOMEM) {
    reset();
    return NULL;      /* out of memory */
  }

  return (c == EOF && i == 0) ? NULL : line;
}


/* split: split line into fields */
static int split(void)
{
  char *p, **newf;
  char *sepp; /* pointer to temporary separator character */
  int sepc;   /* temporary separator character */
  nfield = 0;
  if (line[0] == '\0')
    return 0;

  strcpy(sline, line);
  p = sline;

  do {
    if (nfield >= maxfield) {
      maxfield *= 2;      /* double current size */
      newf = (char **) realloc(field,  maxfield * sizeof(field[0]));
      if (newf == NULL)
        return NOMEM;
      field = newf;
    }

    if (*p == '"')
      sepp = advquoted(++p);  /* skip initial quote */
    else
      sepp = p + strcspn(p, fieldsep);

    sepc = sepp[0];

    printf("%d", sepp[0]);   // Debug

    sepp[0] = '\0';       /* terminate field */
    field[nfield++] = p;
    p = sepp + 1;
  } while (sepc == ',');

  return nfield;
}

/* advquoted: quoted field; return pointer to next separator */
static char *advquoted(char *p)
{ … }

/* csvfield:  return pointer to n-th field */
char* csvfield(int n)
{
  if (n < 0 || n >= nfield)
    return NULL;
  return field[n];    // This is the problem!
}

/* csvnfield:  return number of fields */
int csvnfield(void)
{
  return nfield;
}

/* csvtest main: test CSV library */
int main(void)
{
  int i;
  char *line;

  while ((line = csvgetline(stdin)) != NULL) {
    printf("line = `%s'\n", line);
    for (i = 0; i < csvnfield(); i++)
      printf("field[%d] = `%s'\n", i, csvfield(i));  // This line is a problem
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I can't figure out is the `char**` field which I believe is a pointer to an array of pointers to strings/character array/fields.
Therefore `field[n]` should contain pointer to the string i.e the address of the string and not the string itself. But this doesn't seem to be the case since when it is accessed in the `printf()` statement, the function `csvfield(i)` returns the value and not the pointer to the nth field.

I have browsed many websites trying to understand `char **` but the information is very, very limited. One website said that `char *` is a pointer to a character array but `char**` is a pointer to pointer to char. Another website talks about `char **` type being a scalar type. But I'm still fuzzy regarding this `char **`.

Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: An excellent book to be reading!

Comment: So... you are asking why `printf("%s\n", x);` prints the string, when `x` is a `char *`  ? Pretty sure that is covered much earlier in the book :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor issue in your transcription of the code from the book, and then there's the understanding necessary for `char **field;` to make sense.

In my copy of the book, the first line you are having difficulty understanding is written differently from what you quote.  Your quote is first; what the book says comes second:

```
 field = (char **) malloc(maxfield*sizeof(field));
 field = (char **) malloc(maxfield*sizeof(field[0]));
```

I'm relieved, because the official version is correct, though the first will work somewhat by coincidence.  The difference is the one allocates an amount of space for `maxfield` copies of a `char **`, whereas what is required is space for that many `char *` values.  Now as it happens, `sizeof(char **) == sizeof(char *)`, but it is best to be clear about what is asked for.  For a pointer `ptr` of type `Xyz *`, the idiom to allocate an array of `N` values is:

```
Xyz *ptr = (Xyz *)malloc(N * sizeof(*ptr));
```

where `*ptr` is of type `Xyz`, of course, and is also equivalent to `ptr[0]`, the notation used in the book.

Now, about the `char **field`…what is allocated can be understood with a diagram like this:

```
+-------+     +----------+
| field |---->| field[0] |
+-------+     +----------+
              | field[1] |
              +----------+
              | field[2] |
              +----------+
              | field[3] |
              +----------+
                  ...
```

When it is initially allocated, each of `field[0]`, `field[1]`, … has no initialized value and points nowhere.  In the code, as fields are parsed, space is allocated for each field as follows:

```
 char **         char *          char
+-------+     +----------+     +----------------+
| field |---->| field[0] |---->| String value 1 |
+-------+     +----------+     +----------------+    +----------+
              | field[1] |-------------------------->| String 2 |
              +----------+     +--------------+      +----------+
              | field[2] |---->| Third String |
              +----------+     +--------------+
              | field[3] |
              +----------+
                  ...
```

The elements of the array are contiguous; the strings are not contiguous.  Each element of the array is a `char *`, of course.

Now, inside `csvfield(int n)`, the function returns either NULL or `field[n]`.  As you can see from the diagram, the values `field[n]` are `char *`.  So the code is correct, and it does return a `char *` as the function signature states.  (The code compiles cleanly, too, even under stringent warning levels.)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `char**` can be consider as  an array of pointers to strings/character array/fields. How did you `printf` the `csvfield(i)`? If you did it with format "`...%s...`" sure it will output the string value; if you want the pointer address, use the format "`...%p...`".

Comment: SO instead of the printf statement above, I use printf("field[%d] = `%s'\n", i, *field[n]) will it give me the same answer?

Comment: <code>*field[n]</code> will get the first character value of field[n], and can't be used <code>%s</code> to print, <code>%c</code> instead. Not test, try it yourself.

Comment: The code in the question shows `printf("field[%d] = '%s'\n", i, csvfield(i));` which does indeed use `%s`.  And to answer razi's question, 'cheating' and using `printf("field[%d] = '%s'\n", i, field[i]);` would yield the same result (but `n` is not defined in the context where `i` is defined), and using `*field[i]` would attempt to print a single character as a string, which will not work well (but `printf("field[%d][0] = '%c'\n", i, *field[i]);` or  `printf("field[%d][0] = '%c'\n", i, field[i][0]);` would work fine).